# SIP/2.0 439 First Hop Lacks Outbound Support error

Tags: sip

I am getting a `SIP/2.0 439 First Hop Lacks Outbound Support` while I am trying to register a softphone against the PBX.

what are the possible causes for 439 error code. Do we need to create a Remote Proxy on the signaling server?

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting a SIP/2.0 439 First Hop Lacks Outbound Support while I am
> trying to register a softphone against the PBX.
> what are the possible causes for 439 error code.

The 439 response code is issued by a Registrar to indicate that support of oubound specification is requested by the softphone but not supported by the PBX. (In that case, there is also other possibilities)

> Do we need to create a Remote Proxy on the signaling server?

I depends of your telecom policies but I bet that if you remove Outbound request on the softphone side it will work nicely.

In practice, you should check with wieshark if the softphone generate that SIP header :  `Require: outbound`